# HTML/CSS Footer troubles

Tags: html, css, footer

I've looked on previous SO posts and tuts but have not had any luck with my own code.  My footer will not stick to the bottom of the page (not the window).  I don't want content to scroll through my footer.  The page sizes vary greatly in length and want to have a footer at the bottom at all times.

The leftcol, rightcol, and footer are all in the container.  Any help would be awesome.

My HTML is structured as so:

```
<body>
 <div id = "container">
  <div id = "leftcol">
      <h2></h2>
       </p>
  </div>
  <div id = "rightcol">
      <h2></h2>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div id ="footer">
       <p>...........</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    height: auto;
    color: #252525;
    }

#container {
    display: block;
    width: 1024px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

#leftcol {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 5px 5px 15px;
    width: 660px;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

#rightcol {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 5px 5px 780px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 275px;
    height: auto;
    }

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: show us some HTML code too and make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example

Comment: agree, it is not clear what you want, and what is going wrong...

Comment: I added the basic HTML stucture

Comment: When I've attempted other jsfiddle ex and other methods, it seems to ignore my floated leftcol and rightcol.  Possibly has something to do with those two elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to move your footer outside of the container element and the body element and use position:absolute; and bottom:0; to always fix it to the bottom of the html element.

I say outside of the body as, although majoritively the body tag takes o the height of the html element, there are some versions of IE in which this isn't the case. As you haven't pasted your HTML i obviously can't show you the revised html but you're css should look like:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, moving the #footer outside of the body still only sets it to the bottom of the screen, not the height of the content shown.

Comment: it sets it to the height of the body tag, which will expand as the content expands, so when the content is too small for the viewport then it will always appear at the bottom of it, when the content is larger than the viewport then it does what you would expect and still be below the content (and not overlay the content by fixing in position at the bottom of the window).

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I got it to work.  I added a sticky navigation (top menu) and it was causing my leftcol to jump after the scroll.  So when I positioned it relative, it threw my footer off (which was causing this thread).  Taking it out of the body fixed it after some other tweaks.  Thanks @JamieM23!